# Need Advice on Java Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am new to java and would like to use a Swing Timer in my form.  I would like it to display in a jTextField.  I have these lines of code for the Timer:

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener(); 
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, actionListener);
```

It states ActionListener is abstract and cannot be instantiated.  How do I work with this and How do I get the "timer" to be displayed in my JTextField?  Much appreciation in advance.

Comment: Please [search on the error message before asking](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+class+is+not+abstract+and+does+not+override+) as this sort of question has been well asked and answered previously.

Comment: Also, note, that Timer does not have (long, ActionListener) constructor. 
You have to pass TimerTask into the constructor. The code will look like
       `Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // code on timer invocation
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5000, 5000);`
This snippet will execute code inside of `run` method every 5 seconds and you should be able to update `jTextField` from it

Comment: While @AntonDovzhenko's advise was well meaning, it is incorrect. You should not use the `java.util.Timer` class as he's suggesting, but rather stick with the `javax.swing.Timer` also known as the "Swing Timer" which you were originally using. The Swing Timer is much more thread-safe for Swing GUI's than the util Timer.

Comment: And it **does** have a constructor that takes an int and an ActionListener.

Comment: @AntonDovzhenko: please see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025715/javax-swing-timer-vs-java-util-timer-inside-of-a-swing-application) for more on this issue.

Comment: I was referencing to `java.util.Timer`, but you are right, for swing code `javax.swing.Timer` mayb e more suitable

Comment: I know what you were referencing, and there's no maybe about it. The util Timer is absolutely **guaranteed** to call the TimerTask code off of the EDT. It is dangerous to use this in a Swing GUI.